# jquery live function not detecting ajax call change

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dom

```
function hideClose(){

        var unreplied_hide_close_btn = jQuery('.commentbox-gray:not(.private-note)').length; 

        var close_button = jQuery("a[data-status-name='Closed'][data-cnt-id='cnt-note']");

        if(unreplied_hide_close_btn > 0)
        {
            jQuery('#close_ticket_btn').show();

            close_button.show();

            if(jQuery("#helpdesk_ticket_status > option[value='5']").length <= 0)
            {  
                jQuery("#helpdesk_ticket_status").append('<option value="5">Closed</option>');
            }

        }

        else
        {

            jQuery("#helpdesk_ticket_status > option[value='5']").remove().end();

            jQuery('#close_ticket_btn').hide();

              var button_text =  jQuery("[data-public-text='Add Public Note'] span").text();

             if(( button_text == "Add Private Note"))
             {
                close_button.hide();
             }

             else
             {
               close_button.show();
             }


        }
    }
```

Here is a function that toggles close button if there is an element with class "Comment 
box" which is not "private-note".

I'm calling this function when the DOM is ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 


        setInterval(function(){ 

            hideClose();  

        },500);

        jQuery('.commentbox').livequery(function(){

            hideClose();

        });

    });
```

There are ajax calls which modify the DOM when notes are added.
Also there is a delete option on the note which are carried out through AJAX.
Calling the function inside setInterval will check for every half a second because notes
can be added at any moment.
When AJAX is carried out for adding a note, the function is getting called.
But the function is not called when a note is deleted.
The variable "unreplied_hide_close_btn" is not updating after element is deleted.
From what I observered, the AJAX call for deleting the note is Aborting the setInterval.
Even livequery function is not working. I also tried live, on, bind functions. 
I want to know if there is a way to check all the DOM changes so that can be used alternative to setInterval.
If there isn't a way other than setInterval, please help me with why the function hideClose is not getting called after note is deleted.

Here is the AJAX call for deleting the note.

```
<a class="red_links conv-action-icon conv-actions-delete tooltip" href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Remove this from the ticket conversation?')) { new Ajax.Request('/helpdesk/tickets/4/notes/1000313643', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'delete'}); }; return false;" data-original-title="Delete" twipsy-content-set="true">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Which Jquery version you using? I believe Jquery has it .on function for live query

Comment: I also tried the .on function. setInterval is some how not firing the hideClose() function after the ajax request is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a success callback function to your AJAX delete request. On the request comes back success, it get called and you fire a function that removes it from the DOM.

Also, I think you might want consider another option other than setting an interval for checking for messages. It's ideal that you only run a function when you need it, not just checking if something exists.

Comment: The ajax success call back cannot be added as the it is in production. However, the DOM events can be handled on the client side where we can update the code on templates. Is there a way other than listening to ajax success?